# Video not playing in Android PhoneGap application using HTML5

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video

I am trying to play video in Android PhoneGap application using HTML5 video tag.But it is only showing a blank screen with the controls.I have also tried by putting the videos in SD card and also inside the assert folder.

Any idea how to play the video??

Answer (score 4):

Check it..
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this plugin [fileOpener Plugin](https://github.com/michalzubkowicz/FileOpener/tree/cordova-2.8.0). it will successfully play your all videos from Assets folder i also have tested this plugin result in Samsung Galaxy S3 and tablet and in browsers as well